# 'str' object has no attribute 'loc' when using dataframe string name

Tags: python

I have dataframe's name like this df_1,df_2, df_3... df_10, now I am creating a loop from 1 to 10 and each loop refers to different dataframe which name is df+ loop name

```
name=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
for na in name:
  data=f'df_{na}'.iloc[:,0]
```

if I do like above, I got an error of AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'

so I need to convert the string into dataframe's name

how to do it?

Comment: Put your dataframes in a list and iterate over the list. In the future, don't create multiple dataframes like that. Use a dictionary instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our chat, you're trying to make 100 copies of a single dataframe. Since [making variable variables is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables), use a dict instead:

```
names = ["df_" + int(i) for i in range(1, 101)]
dataframes = {name: df.copy() for name in names} # df is the existing dataframe
for key, dataframe in dataframes.items():
    temp_data = dataframe.iloc(:, 0)
    do_something(temp_data)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240736/discussion-between-mattdmo-and-roudan).

Comment: Thanks Matt, I appreciate your help today